# Solving an initial-value Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image: Initial Value Problem]

Been struggling with this problem for a few hours now. I am trying to solve to find what i is equal to. Not really sure how to go about it.

i=?

Comment: Is this related to *Mathematica*, the software?

Comment: If it is a Mathematica question, use `DSolve`.  Otherwise, please move the question to the mathematics or physics sites.

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply the equation through by $e^{Rt/L}/L$ the left side will become the output of a product rule, namely the derivative of $e^{Rt/L}i$. Integrate both sides to get $e^{Rt/L}i=$ junk +C.  Solve for $i$ and then use the initial condition to determine $C$.